# How to make dokku deploy app to https connection only

Tags: security, https, deployment, lets-encrypt, dokku

I added domain to my dokku app

```
dokku domains:add myapp example.com
```

then I encrypted the app connection

```
dokku letsencrypt myapp
```

the problem is when I deployed my app it deployed to `http` and `https` connections

```
=====> Application deployed:
       http://example.com
       https://example.com
```

My question is how to make dokku deploy app to `https` connection only

> The reason behind make dokku only deploy app to `https` connection
>
> 1. Because if app deploy to `http` connection then the attacker can access my app via requested `http` connection `http://example.com` using postman (for example or other tool). An example of this case is `heruko.com` it is encrypted using [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) but if you try to make request using http connection `http://heruko.com` via postman then success response will returned.
> 2. Another reason that if the `https` certificate expires then the attacker can access my app via http connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dokku should redirect any requests to http-URLs to the respective https-URLs. So your visitors should be protected.

It is not a problem if an attacker accesses your app using http. The only difference is that anyone between your server and the hacker could intercept and modify the request data. But your server is not less secured when the http-URL is used.

Https is only used to protect the data between your visitors and your server. It does not protect your server in any way.